# Unable to catch XML exception/error in PHP

Tags: php, xml, exception

I am not able to catch exception with below code. Can anyone help me with this thing?

```
try
{
    $xml_emp_name = $xpath->evaluate("//EMPLOYEES[ID='" . $emp_id . "']/EMP-NAME/text()")->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: *Which Exception*? Please document, it's missing in your question (and as you do try-catch you also could consider that there is not Exception because otherwise it has been caught.

Comment: Your code is prone to xpath injection. Fix that first. The error then goes away automatically when you validate *return* values. You're missing the basic principles of *input validation* and *return value validation*. All you need to do is to take more care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is prone to xpath injection. Fix that first. The error then goes away automatically (because the xpath can not become syntactically invalid). Also you need to check/validate *return* values.

So you're missing the basic principles of *input validation* and *return value validation*. All you need to do is to take more care.

*Input validation:*

You directly inject the variable `$emp_id` into the xpath string for substitution:

```
"//EMPLOYEES[ID='" . $emp_id . "']/EMP-NAME/text()"
```

However at that place you can not have a single quote inside that string. Instead check the input value (Validation) or filter/streamline it (Sanitization). For exampe, validate that it does not contain a single quote or sanitize for a numeric value. Here the second:

```
$expression = sprintf('//EMPLOYEES[ID="%d"]/EMP-NAME/text()', $emp_id);
$result     = $xpath->evaluate($expression);
```

This little call to [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) takes care that only numeric integer values are being used. They never contain quotes, so the expression is always valid. Invalid values that are no number will become `0`. As it's the general principle to never assign the ID `0` this should normally not cause any issue in a well designed system. If you want to do the filtering more granular please see [***Data Filtering*** in the PHP manual](http://php.net/book.filter).

*return value validation*

In your code you just take over the return value of the result with very little checks (actually no checks). That is wrong. For each method or function you use you need to look it up in the PHP manual and check the documentation for all *possible* return values. Here the method is [`DOMXpath::evaluate()`](http://php.net/DOMXpath.evaluate), click the link and locate the ***Return Values*** section. You find this for each method and function in the PHP manual.

When you read the documentation also figure out which kind of error-handling a method makes use of. Does it *throws exceptions* (and if yes, which ones?) or does it show an error-condition with it's return value (like in your case)? This information is needed to decide whether to do try/catch as you did (and which is wrong because it does not throw exceptions) or if you need to check the return value:

```
$expression = sprintf('//EMPLOYEES[ID="%d"]/EMP-NAME/text()', $emp_id);
$result     =  $xpath->evaluate($expression);

if (!$result) {
    throw new Exception(
        sprintf('No such employee (id: %s)', var_export($emp_id, true))
    );
}
```

This example turns a *falsy* return value into an exception with an individual exception message. You also might want to consider a different exception, the [SPL offers some pre-defined exceptions](http://php.net/spl.exceptions).

I hope this answer helps you to deal with this issue and forthcoming ones.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it so wonderfully. But i am not yet able to resolve my problem ---- I am facing "Trying to get property of non-object" on line `$result  =  $xpath->evaluate($expression);` --- It throws exception but also gives a PHP error on evaluate. Is there anything else that i need to take care of? Thanks again!

Comment: Please ignore the previous comment - it has worked fine, i was doing a minor syntax error. Your solution is perfect for my case.

Answer (score 2):

DOMXPath::evaulate does not throw exceptions. [domxpath evaluate](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.evaluate.php)

> If the expression is malformed or the contextnode is invalid, DOMXPath::evaluate() returns FALSE.

Try

```
$xml_emp_name = $xpath->evaluate("//EMPLOYEES[ID='" . $emp_id . "']/EMP-NAME/text()");
if(!$xml_emp_name){
    echo 'Error';
}else{
    $name = $xml_emp_name->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

You try to access a property on a non-object if evaulate fails and returns `false`.

Comment: So how do i avoid PHP error on evaluate - I want to catch this error and show my custom error message --- Like "Invalid employee ID"

Comment: `if(!$xml_emp_name) echo 'Error';`

Comment: that would be after evaluate - it will still throw an error on evaluate statement

Answer (score 0):

`->evaluate` will for some reason not throw any exceptions, so what I would advise is to check if the result is false, then throw an exception:

```
if (($xml_emp_name = $xpath->evaluate("//EMPLOYEES[ID='" . $emp_id . "']/EMP-NAME/text()") ) !== false) {
   $xml_emp_name = $xml_emp_name->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
else {
   // Throw Exception
}
```

Comment: I've never really understood `->evaluate`. Why don't just use `->query`?